# Integrate $x(x^2+1)^3$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

Here is the equation that has to be integrated  and my ans:
$$\int x\left(x^2+1\right)^3dx=\int \left(x^3+x\right)^3=\left(x^3+x\right)^4\dfrac 1{12}+c$$

The correct answer is :

$$
\int x(x^2+1)^3 dx=\frac18 (x^2 + 1) + C
$$

How come?

Comment: How is $x(x^2+1)^3\color{red}{=}(x^3+x)^3=x^3(x^2+1)^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a change of variable $u = x^2+1$ then $du = 2xdx$ so
$$
\int x\left(x^2+1\right)^3 dx
 = \int u^3 \frac{du}{2}
 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{u^4}{4}
 = \frac{\left(x^2+1\right)^4}{8} + C
$$